# FileInput causing ERR_ACCESS_DENIED with enctype="multipart/form-data" and flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

In my simple learning experiment of flask, I have created a form with username,email and file upload. This file will be mailed to other users [Basically an excel sheet]

My script is working great till the last part of file location identification. Now I have read the docs, forums and api of filesystem security and have been trying to use request.files['file'] and enctype="multipart/form-data"

my PageView.html:

```
{% block content %}
<form class="form" action="" method="post" name="DeployerC1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
..
..
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <td class="text-left"><strong>Username</strong></td>
     <td class="text-left"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>{{Users.Userame}}</td>
     <td>{{Users.Email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="file" name=file>
            <p class="help-block">Location of monthly report.</p>
```

.
..
in views.py

```
@app.route('/Sendit', methods=['GET','POST'])
def Sendit():   
..
.       
    if request.method == 'POST':
            .
            ...
            .....
            CredDict = {'Username':Username,'Email':Email}
            for element in FinalList:
                    element.update(CredDict)                
            file = request.files['file']
            print file
            return redirect(url_for('Processed'))

    return render_template('blah.ah.blah')
```

Now, the prob I am facing is if I use enctype, then I get  ERR_ACCESS_DENIED when I click on Submit or Next.

Without enctype, the nextpage proceeds well, but displays only the filename with the warning that I should use enctype. To access the filecontents [basically to store in tmp], I tried to use request.files['file'], but end up ERR_ACCESS_DEINED.

The workaround I can think of is use a separate decorator for file and a separate html for file upload, but this, I dont want to do.
Is it possible to have the username/email input along with file input and Next submit with request.files?

The below is the part of code I plan to use to save file to a tmp location

```
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Any directions would be helpful.

thanks a ton..

Comment: How are you running your application? Are there any errors in the log? Have you tried using a different browser?

Comment: I run by python app/run.py.. 

Sorry for the trouble.. I figured out that the script was directing to a xml instead of xls. [Serves me right for working late night]. I included the ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS for xls and for some reason, xml file is not getting responded. Guess I need another enctype for it.. Thanks again, the webpage is proceeding..